# Linux shell: poll the keyboard button's state

Tags: linux, shell, keyboard

I have a script that is executed periodically in the background.
I want to prevent its execution if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed.

The idea is to poll the keyboard's <kbd>Shift</kbd> button state, and if it's pressed — terminate the script immediately.

Any ideas?  X server is allowed to use: I guess it will help.

**UPD:** I'm currently using this stupid hack:

```
[ $( sh -c 'cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-*kbd & sleep 0.5 ; kill $! 2>/dev/null' | wc -c ) -gt 1 ] && exit
```

The script just detects current keyboard events but does not distinguish them. 0.5sec is the kbd-events watch period. Not very nice, but still works :)

Comment: I would recommend using a GUI window for this. It avoids a lot of nasty issues (terminals do not even transmit this information and evdev requires root access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can monitor key up/down events, but as far as I know, there's no way to tell if the key is *currently* pressed.  If you're OK with that, then...

That implies that the thing listening for the key event has to be running in another thread.  The shell script will have to spawn a program in the background that listens for key events and sends a signal to the parent script on keypress.  You can use [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) to respond to the signal by exiting gracefully.

Check out [KeyPress](http://keypress.sourceforge.net/).  It might give you a good start.

You may also be able to [monitor /dev/input/eventN](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=451442&forum_id=14&gforum_id=0).  [This perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~beppu/Linux-Input-1.02/lib/Linux/Input.pm) may help.

Comment: Thank you! /dev/input/ looks like somthing close enough to the solution! :)

Comment: It _is_ possible to tell if a key is currently pressed. See [`evtest` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/evtest.1.html), `--query` option.